# Is this integral correct (even odd functions)

Tags: calculus, integration, even-and-odd-functions

**ORIGINAL QUESTION:**
Suppose that $f(x)$ is an even function and $\int_0^3 f(x)dx=10$. Find $\int_{-3}^0 f(x)dx$.

What about if it is an odd function?

**MY ANSWER:**
If the function is even wouldn't the answer still be $10$.
and if the function is odd the answer will be $-10$?

I'm having some troubles with even and odd functions, any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Yes you're right.

Comment: You are correct. But you should tell us how you get those answers, otherwise we can't verify your thought process. Next time you ask a question, try to use Mathjax to format your math equations for good readability and conciseness. [Here is a quick guide](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Answer (score 1):

**Case 1 -- $f$ is even :** If $f$ is even, then for all $x$, we have $f(x) = f(-x)$. Then : $$\int_{-c}^0 f(x) dx = \int_c^0 f(-y) (- dy) = \int_0^c f(x) dx$$

---

**Case 2 -- $f$ is odd :** If $f$ is odd, then for all $x$, we have $f(-x) = -f(x)$. Then : $$\int_{-c}^0 f(x) dx = \int_c^0 f(-y) (- dy) = -\int_0^c f(x) dx$$

---

In both cases, we have simply made a change of variable from $x$ to $(-x)$. I guess this clarifies your doubt.

Answer (score 0):

Hint : $\int_{-3}^0 f(x) dx = - \int_3^0 f(-x) dx = \int_0^3 f(-x) dx$